# Link with / and $_GET PHP

Tags: php

i want to create a link similarly localhost/website/index.php/id
Id is the ID selected from DB. How it's possible this in PHP?
I use this for link: localhost/website/index.php?id

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) { action } ?>
```

Comment: The URL structure you want appears to be of an MVC framework designed in PHP. This question can only be answered by explaining the MVC design in detail. Try exploring PHP frameworks, e.g. Codeignitor or Laravel.

Comment: You seem to be looking for url rewriting.

Comment: After seeing the answers, I would like to add that what I have understood from your question is that the link you are using currently is working and you want to further refine it as `localhost/website/index.php/id`. In fact you can even have a URL similar to `localhost/website/index/your-slug-or-db-id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this can be done with something like this

You can use Apache `mod_rewrite` to load subpages dynamically, for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^website/index.php$ website/index.php?id=$1
```

This would be in an `.htaccess` at your root directory.

Hope I helped! -CM

Comment: Works for index.php?id. You don't understood the question correctly.I want to show a message if I am at localhost/website/index.php/id not on localhost/website/index.php?id

Comment: @VladS what webserver are you using?

Comment: I using a Apache Webserver with XAMPP on local and a webhost at HZone @Cole

Comment: Edited to a solution that should work @VladS. -CM

Comment: Thank you. And the PHP code is?

Comment: @VladS `$_GET['id']` would get the ID just as before. -CM

Answer (score -1):

It must be like below:

```
echo <a href="localhost/website/index.php/id">name</a>
```

Then your php code would be like:

```
<?php
if((int)$_REQUEST['id']>0) {
    echo '<a href="localhost/website/index.php/'.(int)$_REQUEST['id'].'">Name</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Works for index.php?id. You don't understood the question correctly.I want to show a message if I am at localhost/website/index.php/id not on localhost/website/index.php?id